# Setting transparent color as strokeColor in Acrobat JS API results in black border

Tags: javascript, api, annotations, acrobat, freetext

my problem is that when I try to set transparent as strokeColor for FreeText annotation when adding one the resulting annotations has black border.

I try to code it like this:

```
this.addAnnot({ type: "FreeText", contents: "TEST", strokeColor: color.transparent, page: 0 });
```

Ane the result is:

[image: Sample of the result]

Is there any way to set transparent as border color for the annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the undocumented property "intent" and set it to "FreeTextTypewriter". That property changes the way the on-page appearance gets generated.

```
this.addAnnot({ type: "FreeText", contents: "TEST", page: 0 ,strokeColor: color.transparent, intent:"FreeTextTypewriter"});
```

Comment: Found out that setting the border width to 0 works with hiding the border. :)